# How to check if a link has been added to a CKEditor/Textarea using ReactJs? and CKEditor

Tags: reactjs

I am using CKEditor with reactjs, and I need to know when a user adding a link in the text area, and I am talking about video links for example youtube.

**I want to check when a user adds a video link so i can grab it and render it in the specific page I want.**

for rendering the video I am using `react-youtube`.

## what i tried and what i got as result.

## 1- I have a field because i am using Formik, as follow

```
<Field
              name="postText"
              render={({ field, form }) => {
                console.log("post text", field.value);
                return editorLoaded ? (
                  <>
                    <CKEditor
                      editor={ClassicEditor}
                      data={field.value}
                      onChange={(event, editor) => {
                        form.setFieldValue(field.name, editor.getData());
                      }}
                    />
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <> </>
                );
              }}
            />
```

## 2- I did a console.log

```
      console.log("post text", field.value);
```

## 3- The result of the console.

```
post text <p>Hello this is a video link&nbsp;</p>

<figure class="media">
<oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaZxUCWAjb0"></oembed> 
</figure>
```

so now is there a way to find out the link and save the database?

i really appreciate your help:)

Comment: You should be able to listen to events fired by the embed plugin. The event system allows you to listen to various events: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/event-system.html#listening-to-events and MediaEmbed (I'm  guessing this is used) should fire events that you might be able to leverage: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_media-embed_mediaembed-MediaEmbed.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah i checked them out, and still i am confused how to do it, i would appreciate if you give a sample so i can get have a better understanding:_)